# Enum case switch not found in type

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2, reactive-cocoa

Can someone please help me with this.

I have the following `public enum`

```
public enum OfferViewRow {
    case Candidates
    case Expiration
    case Description
    case Timing
    case Money
    case Payment

}
```

And the following mutableProperty:

```
private let rows = MutableProperty<[OfferViewRow]>([OfferViewRow]())
```

In my init file I use some reactiveCocoa to set my MutableProperty:

```
rows <~ application.producer
    .map { response in
        if response?.application.status == .Applied {
            return [.Candidates, .Description, .Timing, .Money, .Payment]
        } else {
            return [.Candidates, .Expiration, .Description, .Timing, .Money, .Payment]
        }
}
```

But now the problem, when I try to get the value of my enum inside my rows it throws errors. Please look at the code below.

```
 func cellViewModelForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ViewModel {
        guard
            let row = rows.value[indexPath.row],
            let response = self.application.value
            else {
                fatalError("")
        }

        switch row {
        case .Candidates:
             // Do something
        case .Expiration:
            // Do something
        case .Description:
           // Do something
        case .Timing:
           // Do something
        case .Money:
           // Do something
        case .Payment:
           // Do something
        }
    }
```

It throws an error: `Enum case 'some' not found  in type 'OfferViewRow` on the line `let row = rows.value[indexPath.row]`

And on every switch statements it throws: `Enum case 'Candidates' not found  in type '<<Error type>>`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you try `public enum OfferViewRow: Int` as declaration of enum

Comment: Don't help, also tried the !

Comment: What is the type of the constant `row`?

Answer (score 14):

The guard statement wants an optional, as hinted by "Enum case 'some'" in the error message.

But `rows.value[indexPath.row]` is not `Optional<OfferViewRow>`, it is a raw `OfferViewRow`. So it won't enter a guard statement.

Move `let row = rows.value[indexPath.row]` one line up: Swift takes care of bounds checking, and will crash if indexPath.row is out of bounds.