# Swift : Enum case not found in type

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, mutating-function

I have been searching for many questions here, I found one with similar title [Enum case switch not found in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815171/enum-case-switch-not-found-in-type), but no solution for me.

I'd like to use enum with mutation of itself to solve question, what is the next traffic light color, at individual states.

```
enum TrafficLights {
    mutating func next() {
        switch self {
        case .red:
            self = .green
        case .orange:
            self = .red
        case .green:
            self = .orange
        case .none:
            self = .orange
        }
    }
}
```

I have put all cases as possible options and it's still returning error:

> Enum 'case' not found in type 'TrafficLights'

Comment: I was confused, I thought if all cases are inside the mutating func, they do not need to be outside that func to be defined. Thanks.

Comment: I hope this isn't been used for real traffic lights...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cases must be declared outside of the function:

```
enum TrafficLights {

case green
case red
case orange
case none

mutating func next() {
    switch self {
    case .red:
        self = .green
    case .orange:
        self = .red
    case .green:
        self = .orange
    case .none:
        self = .orange
    }
  }
}
```

Advisable:- Go through [Enumeration - Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

Comment: Thank you! My Basic fault. Now it works, so now if I remove case .none from mutating function, it would still have this case defined, even if I don't need to have next step after that state. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Documentation:- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html.. :)Happy coding

Comment: It is also possible to add these cases in one line, so `case green, red, orange, none`.

Answer (score 11):

I was having an issue with the same error when converting an Int to a custom enum:

```
switch MyEnum(rawValue: 42) {
case .error:
    // Enum case `.error` not found in type 'MyEnum?'
    break
default:
    break
}
```

The issue is that `MyEnum(rawValue: 42)` returns an optional. Unwrap it or provide a non-optional to allow switching on the enum:

```
switch MyEnum(rawValue: 42) ?? MyEnum.yourEnumDefaultCase {
case .error:
    // no error!
    break
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to user another way of unwrapping such as default value with `??` :  `(MyEnum(rawValue: 42) ?? MyEnum.error)`